# Compactness of the Hilbert cube without the Axiom of Choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice, gn.general-topology, reference-request

I am just curious: is there a published proof of the compactness of the [Hilbert cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube) that does not use the Axiom of Choice, or is it well known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this paper by Peter Loeb:

- Peter A. Loeb, [*A new proof of the Tychonoff Theorem*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2314411), The American Mathematical Monthly **72** (1965), no. 7, 711--717.

Here is the theorem from this paper that implies that the usual Hilbert cube is compact without using the AC.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $\{\,X_\nu\mid\nu\in I\,\}$ be a family of compact spaces which is indexed by a set $I$ on which there is a well-ordering $\ge$. If $I$ is an infinite set, let there also be a choice function $F$ on the collection $\{\,C\mid\text{$C$ is closed},\ C\ne\varnothing,\ \text{$C\subset X_\nu$ for some $\nu$}\,\}$.  Then the product space $\prod_{\nu\in I}X_\nu$ is compact in the product topology.

For the usual Hilbert cube $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$, the function $F$ can, for example, select the least element in every compact subset of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 21):

If by the Hilbert cube you mean only $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ then the answer is yes. There is such proof, you can find it in Herrlich's **The Axiom of Choice** as Theorem 3.13.

If you mean the general case of $[0,1]^I$ then the answer is no, to prove that all Hilbert cubes are compact is equivalent to BPIT/The ultrafilter lemma/Tychonoff for Hausdorff spaces. The proof of that you can find in the same book as Theorem 4.70.

Comment: On the other hand, for any ordinal $\alpha$ the compactness of the Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^\alpha$ can be proved without AC or BPIT, usinng the completeness of the lexicographic order on $[0,1]^\alpha$ (or even on $\{0,1\}^\alpha$).

Answer (score 16):

The compactness of the Hilbert cube follows (without AC) from the compactness of $2^\omega$, since $[0,1]$ as well as $[0,1]^\omega$ are continuous images of $2^\omega$.

(Conversely, $2^\omega$ is a closed subset of the Hilbert cube.)

The compactness of $2^\omega$ is just König's lemma for trees of binary sequences, which is easy to prove (hence certainly well-known) without AC.  (I think this is called "weak König's lemma", an important principle in reverse mathematics.)

Comment: But Koenig's lemma does require a minute amount of choice. It is not needed in the case of $2^\omega$ because that is a linearly ordered set, and every level is finite, so we get a choice function.

Comment: Compactness of $2^\omega$ can also easily be seen by identifying it with the Cantor set, a closed subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Andrej, it depends on your formulation of the lemma. If you formulate it over a countable tree - sure. But if you only state that the tree has $\omega$ levels and each is finite then you do need the axiom of choice. See Jech's "The Axiom of Choice" for details, Chapter 7 somewhere around the end.

Comment: Clearly, you should understand my comment in the form that is relevant to pointing out that the general case of Koenig's lemma does require choice. I have seen more than enough people thinking that the existence of free ultrafilters is equivalent to the axiom of choice, just because you are using Zorn's lemma.

Comment: I don't understand what you are arguing about.  Asaf, Andrej and I agree that the version of König's lemma that is needed here does not need AC. 

Answer (score 2):

Some of the comments in Goldstern's answer look like they express doubt as to whether choice is required. Here is a proof without choice, in gory detail, just to make sure. The trick is to notice that the construction of an infinite branch $\alpha$ in an infinite binary tree $T$ requires no appeal to the axion of choice because we can *specify a concrete choice*: go left if you can, otherwise go right.

The Hilbert cube is a continuous image of the Cantor space $2^\omega$ of infinite binary sequences with the product topology. Thus it suffices to show that $2^\omega$ is compact. Given a finite binary sequence $a = [a_1, \ldots, a_n]$, denote by $|a| = n$ its length, and let $B_a = \lbrace \alpha \in 2^\omega \mid a = [\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{|a|}] \rbrace$ be the basic open subset of those sequences that start with $a$.

Consider any cover $(B_{a_i})_{i \in I}$ of $2^\omega$. We build a binary tree $T$ which consists of those finite binary sequences $a$ for which $B_a$ is not contained in any $B_{a_i}$, $$T = \lbrace a \in 2^{*} \mid \forall i \in I . B_a \not\subseteq B_{a_i} \rbrace.$$
In other words, we put in $T$ any finite sequence $a$ such that all of its prefixes are *not* in $(a_i)_{i \in I}$. Let us show that $T$ has bounded height, i.e., there is $n$ such that every branch in $T$ has lebgth at most $n$.

Suppose on the contrary that the height of $T$ is unbounded. Then we can build an infinite path $\alpha$ in $T$ by recursion as follows. (This is König's lemma, saying that an unbounded binary tree has an infinite path.) We make sure that at each stage $n$ the subtree of $T$ at $[\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n]$ has unbounded height.
Start with the empty sequence $[]$. The tree at $[]$ is all of $T$, which has unbounded height by assumption. If $[\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n]$ has been constructed, let $T'$ be the subtree of $T$ at $[\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n]$. One or both of the trees
$$T_0' = \lbrace b \in T' \mid b_{n+1} = 0 \rbrace$$
and
$$T_1' = \lbrace b \in T' \mid b_{n+1} = 1 \rbrace$$
have unbounded height. If $T_0'$ does, set $\alpha_{n+1} = 0$, otherwise set $\alpha_{n+1} = 1$. (At this point we did *not* appeal to the axiom of choice, but we did appeal to *excluded middle*.) This concludes the construction of $\alpha$. Now we have a problem since $\alpha$ is covered by some $B_{a_i}$, and so $a_i$ is a prefix of $\alpha$, but this contradicts the definition of $T$.

Now we know that the height of $T$ is bounded by some $n$. Consider the subset $J \subseteq I$ of those indices $j \in I$ for which $|a_j| \leq n + 1$. As there are only finitely many binary sequences of length at most $n+1$, the set $J$ is finite. But since every sequence of length $n+1$ has some $j \in J$ such that $a_j$ is its prefix, $(B_{a_j})_{j \in J}$ is a finite cover of $2^\omega$.

Comment: *No one* in the comments to Goldstern's answer has *any* doubts that the axiom of choice is unneeded.

Comment: Furthermore, let $S=\bigcup_{n\in\omega} P_n$ be a disjoint union of pairs such that no infinite set of pairs has a choice function. Let $T$ be the tree of finite choice functions from an initial segment of $\omega$, that is $g\in T$ is a function from some $n\in\omega$ into $S$ such that $g(i)\in P_i$ for $i<n$. This is an infinite binary tree, but it has no branch.

Comment: Why are you coming up with stuff that is irrelevant to this question?

Comment: I fixed the first sentence so as to make it as clear that nobody had doubts about choice as you made it clear in the comments that you had no such doubts ;-)

Comment: Andrej, first I thank you for removing that line. Second, the reason I am coming up with things so irrelevant is that your phrasing is *wrong*. I gave you an example of an infinite binary tree without an infinite path. Infinite does not mean countably infinite, or even Dedekind-infinite without the axiom of choice. It is important to make this distinction because while I know it, and I am sure that you and Goldstern are well aware of this distinction not all the readers are. The relevant changes are not *big* and they are important. Next thing people insist that cardinals are always ordinals..

Comment: Ok, so if I say that "infnite" means "has an injection from natural numbers", would that be ok?

Comment: Of course. But that would require a tiny bit of the axiom of choice. :-) You can simply replace it with "Dedekind-infinite", which means exactly that and then the result is choice free. I know I'm nitpicky, but we are all mathematicians, aren't we? :-) [Well, in the broad sense of the word... to include Ph.D. students!]

Comment: I got rid of all talk of infinite sets (note that "an infinite path" is about defining a function on $\mathbb{N}$) and replaced those by unbounded height. Now are you happy? By the way, if I define that a tree is infinite when it has an injection from natural numbers, then I do not see where choice comes in. But the thing which is unecessarily complicated is that we have to show that a non-infinite thing is finite, i.e., bounded by some $n$. It is better to just prove directly that the relevant tree has bounded height

Comment: Existence of a countably infinite subset is equivalent to Dedekind-infinite. Without choice not all infinite sets are necessarily Dedekind-infinite. Certainly if a set is dense in the real numbers we cannot have that it is _finite_. But we can have it Dedekind-finite, i.e. infinite without a countably infinite subset. Philosophically I have no problem calling something infinite if it cannot be bijected with a finite ordinal; but I do have a problem calling something "finite" just because it has no countably infinite subset.

Comment: Dedekind-infinite is the wrong definition anyhow, as it does not work in general (only in the very limited environment of classical set theory), so I do not particularly care about it.

Comment: Similarly to Andrej's argument above, one can give an AC-free proof of the following result: if $X$ is a countable graph, every finite subgraph of $X$ has a good coloring with $k$ colors ($k$ is finite) then so has $X$. 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers and sorry about a silly question. I have also figured out that it can be proved using the usual complete metric on the usual (countable product) Hilbert cube and finite $\epsilon$-nets.

---

**Update.** Here is a proof.

Let $X = [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\times[-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}]\times[-\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8}]\times\dotsb$ be a Hilbert cube endowed with its $\ell_\infty$ metric.
For every positive integer $k$, let $N_k$ be the “natural” $\frac{1}{2^k}$-net for $X$.

Let $\mathcal U$ be a given family of open sets such that no finite subfamily of $\mathcal U$ covers $X$.
Then let $S_k$ be the set of those elements of $N_k$ which are within the distance of $\frac{1}{2^k}$ from the complement of any finite union of elements of $\mathcal U$.
Each $S_k$ is nonempty.
For all $m$ and $n$, the distance from any point of $S_m$ to the set $S_n$ is at most $\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Assume that the points of $X$ are ordered by the lexicographic order of their coordinates.
Take the “first” $x_1\in S_1$ (i.e. the smallest in the order), then the “first” $x_2\in S_2$ that is within the distance of $\frac{3}{4}$ from $x_1$, then the “first” $x_3\in S_3$ that is within the distance of $\frac{3}{8}$ from $x_2$, and so forth.
The obtained sequence $\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy.
Its limit is not in any element of $\mathcal U$.

Comment: You have to be careful how you formulate this proof.  The implication "Every totally bounded complete metric space is compact" uses AC, as far as I can see.  

Comment: @Goldstern, probably you are right in general (is the Axiom of Choice for families of finite sets equivalent to the usual one?). In the case of Hilbert cube, the $\epsilon$-nets can be constructed explicitly, so that there will be no problem.

Comment: Alexey far from it. The axiom of choice for families of finite sets do not imply the axiom of choice for families of countable sets, or even countable choice for that matter.